# Socket.IO socket not connecting to server over WIFI

Tags: java, android, sockets, socket.io

Trying to get an android client (on a smartphone) to communicate with a Java server via Socket.IO. They managed to connect *once*, but I haven't managed to reproduce the connection since.

Any help would be appreciated!

(I've verified the host server's IP address, and have tried multiple ports.)

Android Client:

```
import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Socket mSocket;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.0.15:9092");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mSocket.connect();
    }
```

Android permissions contains:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Java server:

```
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.*;

public class IOServer {
    final SocketIOServer server;

    public IOServer()
    {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setHostname("localhost");
        config.setPort(9092);
        server = new SocketIOServer(config);
        server.addConnectListener(new ConnectListener(){
        @Override
        public void onConnect(SocketIOClient client) {
            System.out.println("CONNECTION!");
            System.out.println(client.toString());
        }
      });
      server.start();

       try {
          Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
       server.stop();
    }


}
```

(Client uses: io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3, server uses: com.corundumstudio.socketio)